# R: How can I remove duplicate phrases in a string?

Tags: r, replace, duplicates

Let's say my string is something like

```
mystring = c("Empty String; Empty String;", "Empty String; Empty String; Empty String; Apple is red")
```

'Empty String;' can be repeated more than twice or thrice in a string.
I want to write regex expression so that it looks like:

```
newstring = c("Empty String;", "Empty String; Apple is red")
```

How do I remove the repeated phrase in a string?

Comment: If the repeated strings always end in `;` this can be done with a very simple pattern https://regex101.com/r/5M9yvF/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use a capture group to capture and replace duplicated strings.

- Put everything `(.+?;\\s?)` before a semi-colon `;` inside the capture group
- `sub` the string with the capture group (non-repeating self `\\1`) if it occurs at least two times

```r
sub("(.+?;\\s?){2,}", "\\1", mystring, perl = T)
#[1] "Empty String;"              "Empty String; Apple is red"
```

Comment: could you please explain the capture group regular expression purpose

Comment: @jkatam It's nothing fancy but sure I've added explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple non-regex solution would be exactly what @Thomas Tunde mentioned. Here is how you can do it in R.

```
sapply(strsplit(mystring, ";"), \(x) paste0(unique(trimws(x)), collapse = ";"))

#[1] "Empty String"              "Empty String;Apple is red"
```

Comment: Or `collapse = "; "` if the space after semi-colons is desired.

Comment: Or `sapply(strsplit(mystring, "(?<=;)", perl = T), \(x) paste0(unique(trimws(x)), collapse = " "))` if we want to preserve the semi-colon in the first "Empty String;"

Answer (score -1):

To remove duplicate phrases in a string, you can follow these steps:

1. Split the string into individual phrases or words.
2. Convert the split phrases into a vector.
3. Use the `unique()` function to obtain unique phrases.
4. Join the unique phrases back into a string. R:

```r
remove_duplicate_phrases <- function(string) { 
  phrases <- strsplit(string, "\\s+")[[1]] 
  unique_phrases <- unique(phrases) # Get unique phrases) 
  unique_string <- paste(unique_phrases, collapse = " ") 
  return(unique_string) } 

input_string <- "Hello world hello world! This is a test test." 
result <- remove_duplicate_phrases(input_string) 
print(result)
```

Comment: Python example->

def remove_duplicate_phrases(string):
    phrases = string.split()  # Split string into phrases or words
    unique_phrases = set()
    
    for phrase in phrases:
        unique_phrases.add(phrase)  # Add phrase to set (duplicates will be automatically removed)
    
    unique_string = ' '.join(unique_phrases)
    return unique_string

input_string = "Hello world hello world! This is a test test."
result = remove_duplicate_phrases(input_string)
print(result)

Comment: The question asks for a solution using R.

Comment: 1. Split the string into individual phrases or words.
2. Convert the split phrases into a vector.
3. Use the `unique()` function to obtain unique phrases.
4. Join the unique phrases back into a string.

 R:

    remove_duplicate_phrases <- function(string) {
  phrases <- strsplit(string, "\\s+")[[1]]
  unique_phrases <- unique(phrases)  # Get unique phrases) 
  
  unique_string <- paste(unique_phrases, collapse = " ")
  return(unique_string)
}

input_string <- "Hello world hello world! This is a test test."
result <- remove_duplicate_phrases(input_string)
print(result)

Comment: Next time you can edit your post rather than leaving a comment, I've done this for you this time :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Thomas Tunde.

Your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll be a part of our community and contribute with *your own*, quality posts in the future. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.